# Tags not showing on layouts

Tags: page-layout, tag

I can see tags when I edit the layouts they are enabled on, but when I go to a detail view, they don't show up.

Editing layout looks good, I can see tags. 
[image]

But when I go to the detailed view:
[image]

Any idea what could be preventing them from showing up? They don't show on any of the objects I have enabled tags for.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit. Our instance had topics enabled by default. We don't use Chatter, but you can still enable topics, and they are mutually exclusive with tags. So make sure they are not enabled on objects you want tags to appear on.

[image]